# Show UIAlertView with the application closed

Tags: iphone, ios, uialertview, show

I wonder how to display message with the application closed. O Groupon app for iphone send the message to me with a closed application. Thank you!

Comment: Apple Push Notification Service

Answer (score 2):

Like Nicolas said, it's called push notifications.

Here is a great tutorial if you are new this realm:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12